# Help to proof a Cumulative Distribution Function

Tags: probability

If X is a random variable with a CDF [F(x)] and let r be a positive integer, proof that:

$${[F(x)]}^r$$ is a CDF.

Comment: According to your definition of CDF, what do you need to verify?  Are you able to verify any of those conditions?

Comment: i) it must be monotonic ii)x->inf then CDF=1 iii)x->-inf then CDF=0

Comment: Are you able to verify any of those conditions?

Comment: I think i just did I'll write them up ...

Comment: More interesting : of which random variable is it the CDF ?

Answer (score 0):

If $x\le y$, $0\le F(x)\le F(y)\le 1$, so $0\le F^r(x)\le F^r(y)\le 1$.

Answer (score 0):

CDF

i)${[F(x)]}^r$ is monotonic ($x1 \le x2 \Rightarrow {[F(x1)]}^r\le {[F(x2)]}^r)$
$$ x1\le x2 \Rightarrow (hip) F(x1)\le F(x2) \Rightarrow {[F(x1)]}^r\le {[F(x2)]}^r $$ since r is a positive integer ($\forall z\in ℝ$)

ii)$\lim_{x\to \infty}{[F(x)]}^r= {|lim_{x\to \infty}{F(x)}|}^r =(hip) {[1]}^r=1 $

the other limit is analogous